# Defining Python Functions in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to python and am trying to define a function and then use it in Google App Engine - but I keep getting the error "Error: global name 'cache_email_received_list' is not defined" when I try to execute the function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here is my function:

```
class EmailMessageHandler(BaseHandler2):
def cache_email_sent_list():  #set email_sent_list to memcache
    email_sent_list = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM EmailMessage WHERE sender =:1 ORDER BY created DESC", user_info.username)  
    if email_sent_list:
        string1 = "email_sent_list"
        email_sent_list_cache_id = "_".join((user_info.username, string1))                  
        memcache.set('%s' % email_sent_list_cache_id, email_sent_list, time=2000000)    
        logging.info('**************email_sent_list added to memcache*********')
```

Here is where I am trying to call it:

```
if email_received_list is None and email_sent_list is not None:
    params = {
    'email_sent_list': email_sent_list,         
    }
    cache_email_sent_list()
```

Comment: I don't see `cache_email_received_list` defined or used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache_email_sent_list() is a method of the class EmailMessageHandler therfore the method needs to pass in self a a parameter it will therefore look like this:

```
 class EmailMessageHandler(BaseHandler2):
    def cache_email_sent_list(self):  #set email_sent_list to memcache
        email_sent_list = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM EmailMessage WHERE sender =:1 ORDER BY created DESC", user_info.username)  
        if email_sent_list:
            string1 = "email_sent_list"
            email_sent_list_cache_id = "_".join((user_info.username, string1))                  
            memcache.set('%s' % email_sent_list_cache_id, email_sent_list, time=2000000)    
            logging.info('**************email_sent_list added to memcache*********')
```

Then when you call it from within the class EmailMessageHandler you have to do it like this:

```
self.cache_email_sent_list()
```

If however you are calling it from outside the class EmailMessageHandler you need to first create an instance and then call it using:

```
instanceName.cache_email_sent_list()
```

Comment: Thank you both, Abarnert and Alec-  That fixed the problem.  Just for my own knowledge, can you give me an example of how I would call it from outside of the EmailMessageHandler? Thankyou

Comment: @MattEllis as shown in Roger's answer to use a non static method outside of the class you need to create an instance of that class: `myInstance = MyClass()` then to call the method you do `myInstance.myMethod()` However if `EmailMessageHandler` is a handler I am guessing your unlikely to create an instance of it. Therefore you have 2 options; make the method a static method - see Rogers example. Or put take the method outside the class and make it a global function.

Comment: Unless your handler needs to preserve state (has instance variables) there's really no need to wrap chache_email_sent_list() in a class. My preference would be to implement it as a global function. Unless your handler is part of some hierarchy of handlers where you want to take advantage of inheritance. In that case it would make sense to implement it as a static method within a class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to the previous answers: In your post you define `cache_email_sent_list()` as a function defined in a class definition, which will not work. I think you are confusing instance methods, static methods and functions. There's a prominent difference between these three.

So, as a stylised example:

```
# instance method:
class MyClass(MySuperClass):
    def my_instance_method(self):
        #your code here

# call the instance method:
instance = MyClass() # creates a new instance
instance.my_instance_method() # calls the method on the instance

# static method:
class MyClass(MySuperClass):
    @staticmethod # use decorator to nominate a static method
    def my_static_method()
        #your code here

# call the static method:
MyClass.my_static_method() # calls the static method

# function
def my_function():
    # your code here

# call the function:
my_function() # calls your function
```

Indentation is part of Python syntax and determines how the interpreter handles your code. It takes a bit getting used to but once you've got the hang of it, it's actually really handy and makes your code very readable. I think you have an indentation error in your original post. Just add the correct indentation for the method cache_email_sent_list() and call it on an instance of `EmailMessageHandler` and you're good to go.

Comment: Roger, can you tell me a little bit more about decorators/@staticmethod? -Thanks

Comment: Check out http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808 from Bruce Eckel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with GAE.

The problem is that you've defined `cache_email_sent_list` as a method of the class `EmailMessageHandler`, but you're trying to call it as a top-level function. You can't do that. You need to have an instance of a `EmailMessageHandler` to call it on.

If you're trying to call it from another method of `EmailMessageHandler`, that instance should be available as `self`. For example:

```
self.cache_email_sent_list()
```

If you're trying to call it from elsewhere, it's up to you to figure out what instance you should be calling it on. For example:

```
handler_passed_as_param_to_this_function.cache_email_sent_list()
```

---

Note that your error message is about `cache_email_received_list`, but your code only has `cache_email_sent_list`. I'm guessing that you have parallel code, and the exact same error for both cases, but of course I could be guessing wrong—in which case you'll have to actually show us either the code that goes with your displayed error, or the error that goes with your displayed code…

Comment: Thanks Abarnet- I know this is basic Python, but if I was to call this function in another handler, I would just put:    EmailMessageHandler.cache_email_sent_list() ? -thanks

Comment: @MattEllis: No. You don't call normal methods on classes; you call them on _instances_ of classes. You need to have an `EmailMessageHandler` instance somewhere. It could be a local variable, a parameter to the current function, the `self` parameter to the current method, a global, member attribute of some other object, etc., but some way or another, you have to have an `EmailMessageHandler` if you want to do something with an `EmailMessageHandler`; otherwise, it doesn't make any sense.